# datetime in sql changes to just date in my application

Tags: java, sql-server, date, datetime, jdbc

I have a column in my table from type `datetime`, I am retrieve that column to my java application using jdbc.

my problem is that when I stored `2014-05-13 23:49:18.150` in my database, it becomes `2014-04-13` in my java application.

how to get all the date include time (house, seconds , minutes ).

#### java code

```
callableStatement = con
                    .prepareCall("{call getStatusForOrder(?,?,?,?,?)}");
            callableStatement.setInt(1, order.getID());
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.DATE);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.DATE);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(5, java.sql.Types.BIT);
            callableStatement.execute();
            int statusID = callableStatement.getInt(2);
            Date startTime = callableStatement.getDate(3);
            Date endTime = callableStatement.getDate(4);
            boolean isActive = callableStatement.getBoolean(5);
            System.out.println("IsActive = " + isActive);
            System.out.println("Start Date = " + startTime.toString());
```

Comment: is the DB function getStatusForOrder doing some conversion?

Comment: @sanbhat no it is not

Comment: You mean it becomes 2014-05-13 surely?

Comment: @Will what?  i didn't understant you

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli "my problem is that when I stored 2014-05-13 23:49:18.150 in my database, it becomes 2014-04-13 in my java application." typo?

Comment: it is typo, i in wrong make that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#TIMESTAMP) instead of `Date`, both `datetime` and `datetime2` map to `java.sql.Timestamp`.

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378878.aspx).

PS. Do not forget to use [`callableStatement.getTimestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#getTimestamp%28int%29) instead of `callableStatement.getDate`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#getTimestamp(int)

Comment: so do you mean that I have to change my table to `timestamp` and then change my java object to timestamp?

Comment: No i meant hte lines where you registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.DATE); use java.sql.Types.Timestamp instead, and read these using callableStatement.getTimestamp

Comment: bty, should I change the variable in my stored procedure from datetime to timestamp too ?

Comment: Yes i would use a Timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`DateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) to display it.

- `SHORT` is completely numeric, such as 12.13.52 or 3:30pm
- `MEDIUM` is longer, such as Jan 12, 1952
- `LONG` is longer, such as January 12, 1952 or 3:30:32pm
- `FULL` is pretty completely specified, such as Tuesday, April 12, 1952 AD or 3:30:42pm PST.

Comment: a `java.sql.Date` never has (or should never have) a time portion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must use Timestamp (if I recall it right, haven't programmed Java for a while) instead of Date

Answer (score 1):

`Types.DATE` signifies a JDBC (and SQL) datatype that only has a date component, and no time. You need to use `Types.TIMESTAMP` and the associated `get/setTimestamp(..)` methods and class `java.sql.Timestamp` if you want to have the time portion included.